# Django on MySQL: auto-creation of id field?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

With MySQL, instead of auto-creating the rowid field as done on PostgreSQL, the "slug" field:

```
slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, max_length=128)
```

is used in JOINs, as the "id" field is not created at DB level. The implications are that when doing JOINs the "slug" FK is used, with string data! Of course this is very expensive compared to JOINs using integers.

How do I have Django creating the db-level ID field on MySQL as automatically happens on PostgreSQL?

Comment: Django adds the `id` column to your models by default. Are you saying that you're not seeing that column in MySQL?

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with MySQL vs PostgreSQL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, OK seems like I caused the issue by marking the SlugField as primary_key

Comment: @Sam no I'm not seeing it in MySQL, but the issue must be related to how I defined the primary_key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one primary key per table. Since you've created one yourself, the ORM does not create one for you.

Comment: Indeed. Solution is to simply declare the SlugField as `unique=True` rather than `primary_key=True` and the `id` column is automatically created.